# Use correctly String.Format - C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have two objects of type `string`, where I retrieve a date in dd/MM/yyyy format, I need to format this date I'm getting to show only month and year, in order to use this object in a groupby to group records by month. I'm doing it as follows, retrieving the date in another object to apply the formatting:

```
//Object where I retrieve the date with dd/MM/yyyy normally
public string DataCupom { get; set; }

//Object where I retrieve the value of DataCupom and I'm trying to apply the formatting
public string DataCupomAgrupadoMes { get { return String.Format("{MM:yyyy}", DataCupom); }
```

How can I apply String.Format correctly to retrieve only month and year?

Comment: You have to convert it to a data type that supports that format, like DateTime. String doesn’t understand anything about dates. Or you can just split the string appropriately.

Comment: Also, you should always specify a specific `CultureInfo` when doing formatting - or use `Exact` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string is just a sequence of characters. It has no "date" or "time" semantics. Thus, attempting to format a sequence of characters (sucha as the *DataCupom* string) like it being some data type representing dates or time is not going to work.

In your case, one of the simplest approaches would probably be splitting the *DataCupom* string using '/' as separator, and then assemble the new required string from those parts of the split which represent month and year.

```
   var parts = DataCupom.Split('/');
   return $"{parts[1]}:{parts[2]}";
```

Comment: it was exactly what i needed, thanks!

Comment: Nice and Simple. 

Comment: As this in principle would work, I strongly suggest, not to store timestamps as `string` properties but as `DateTime` and just apply the required formatting when a string representation of that value is needed. What If you discover, you need to update your date by for instance adding two days?

Answer (score 3):

You can try parsing dateString to DateTime and then format.

```
   DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
   dateTime.ToString("MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score -1):

`String.Format()` uses numeric placeholders:

```
return String.Format("{0:MMyyyy}", DataCupom);
```

Where the `0` in the format string means to look at the first additional argument position for the value.

You can also use **interpolation**:

```
return $"{DataCupom:MMyyyy}";
```

or a simple `ToString()` call:

```
return DataCupom.ToString("MM:yyyy");
```

Comment: Does this really work if `DateCupom` is already a `string` and not a `DateTime` (like in OP's question). If yes, starting with what version?